# Program crashing (No idea)

Tags: c++, arrays, crash, new-operator, delete-operator

Program keeps crashing. I'm assuming it's because the pointer is pointing out of bounds when I try to deallocate the memory, but I'm not so sure if that really is the problem. Any idea?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int sze = 3;

    int *ptr1 = new int[sze];

    for (int i = 0; i < sze; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin  >> *(ptr1);  // take the current address and place input to it

        cout << ptr1 << "\n"; // just to check the address

        ptr1++ ; // traverse the array

/*      // remove this and the program will crash
        // re-aim the pointer to the first index
        if(i == 2)
        {
         ptr1-=3;
        } 
        
        // alternative ptr1 = nullptr;
*/

    }
    delete [] ptr1;
```

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `ptr1 -= 3`?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews to move `ptr1` back to its original value, as returned by `new[]`, when the loop is finished

Comment: Your loop increments `ptr1` so the value being passed to the `delete []` is not the same as that produced by the `new []`.    All `delete` expressions have undefined behaviour if not given a pointer returned by a corresponding `new` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are advancing the pointer that `new[]` returns.  You really should not be doing that at all.  You need to pass `delete[]` the same address that `new[]` allocates.  As your commented out code says, you would need to decrement the pointer back to its original value to avoid the crash.

You should use another pointer to iterate your array, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int sze = 3;

    int *ptr1 = new int[sze];
    int *ptr2 = ptr1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sze; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin  >> *ptr2;  // take the current address and place input to it

        cout << ptr2 << "\n"; // just to check the address

        ptr2++ ; // traverse the array
    }

    delete [] ptr1;
}
```

Or, iterate the array using the index already provided by your loop counter, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int sze = 3;

    int *ptr1 = new int[sze];

    for (int i = 0; i < sze; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin  >> ptr1[i];  // take the current address and place input to it

        cout << ptr1[i] << "\n"; // just to check the address
    }

    delete [] ptr1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I get it now. I'm still new to programming and I was experimenting to find problems with this concept of dynamic array, and try to understand why it happened. Until I encounter this issue that I posted, which I can't solve. I didn't know that delete[] requires the same address that was created by new[], and it makes sense because delete[] needs to know where to start de-allocating.

Comment: Not just *where* to start de-allocating, but *how much* to de-allocate. `new[]` stores hidden metadata that `delete[]` uses, most importantly the *number of items* in the array.  `delete[]` can't access that metadata unless it is given the same address that `new[]` returned.